# Does windows 8 hybrid-boot consume more battery than the normal boot when my laptop is turned off?

Tags: windows-8, battery-life, hybrid-boot

I just bought an Asus Vivobook and I've noticed the battery life is not as long as they say in the specs. I'd like to know if the hybrid-boot is causing this or is something related to my laptop.

I'm using it just for translations and some internet surfing.

Thanks

Comment: I would try a full shutdown ( its well documented how to do this ) and compare the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, your laptop doesn't exactly drain battery at all when it's turned off. It's possible that a hybrid boot drains an extremely small amount of extra power, but based on my understanding of what it is I doubt it. In fact it may technically take slightly less, since it results in less time spent on booting.

Manufacturers aren't exactly honest about battery life - the tests they do to calculate it typically involve running the computer at extremely low power, e.g. a word processor at dramatically reduced screen brightness. It's not an accurate representation of battery life with typical use, and you will rarely achieve it unless you deliberately use your computer very sparsely. You can reduce power usage in a few ways, some simpler ones being:

- Don't game while on battery - this causes both processor and graphics
  card to draw a lot more power
- Reduce your screen brightness
- Avoid watching videos, similar reasons to gaming
- Avoid running tons of applications at once; the more your computer is
  doing, the more strain on the memory and, more worryingly, processor,
  so the more power used

Comment: Ok, thanks for that. I'll compare the results. I'm worried because i didn't read the manual and before the first use, i should have connect it for 3 hours. I don't know if I could damage the battery with that, besides, asus says that the batery live is about 5 hours but it only takes about 2.5 - 3 hours.

Comment: I doubt you damaged the battery by not fully charging it before use. Newer laptop batteries are pretty smart and you usually can't damage them just by not reading the manual exactly. It all depends on usage - my laptop might not make it all the way through a 1 hour 30 minute high def movie, but can easily go for three hours web browsing, for example. Your battery is probably fine.